# Playing video prevents sleep on low battery

Tags: video, suspend, power-management, battery

When a video instance is displayed (firefox/chromium html5 video, openshot video editor etc.), the computer does not go to sleep under any circumstances, and it is even forced to stay until the battery drops down to 0.0% power.

This happens easily when the computer is not connected to aa power source and you leave it for a longer time, for example when you fall asleep or when you are unaware that some software or browser tab contains a video. Since dropping battery power to 0.0% is harmful to the hardware, I would like to have always the normal power management behavior for low critical power state.

How can I enforce Ubuntu going to sleep on critical power?

(This could also be a bug, but Ubuntu makes it hard to report a bug without knowing the package.)

Answer (score 0):

Most Apps when playing videos are set to not let the pc go to sleep:

[Check this link for an example](https://techjourney.net/chrome-prevents-windows-from-going-into-sleep-standby-or-hibernation-mode/)

Comment: Thanks, is there also info available of power request overrides on Linux?
Apparently we have to distinguish to aspects of power management:  

(1) user is inactive, here applications may prevent sleep 

(2) critical battery state, this is harmful to hardware and data